# Can Paypal trigger IPN / Webhook without processing data from return_url?

Tags: php, callback, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

To my knowledge, IPN/Webhook are back-end notifications, and are suppose to help merchant-side system reliably receive transaction updates when the front-end return-url could not be used.

However, this is not at all what I experienced during development. Neither IPN or Webhook triggers unless the front-end return is processed. This defeats the whole purpose of "back-end notification".

I'd love to be proven wrong, but I've tested the permutation of Omnipay/PaypalSDK with Order/Auth/Sale, and waited for Webhook/IPN on Sandbox/Live environments, and none works.

Here's what I setup:

- PHP on Laravel, with Omnipay and Paypal SDK
- Docker with ports properly forwarded, so HTTP and HTTPS can be accessed outside LAN
- Enabled Webhook in Paypal's REST App; Enabled IPN in Business profile
- Tested transactions (Sale, Order, Capture) in sandbox mode, all worked
- Tested Paypal's *IPN Simulator* and *Mock Webhook*, both worked
- Tested **Order & Sale** in **Sandbox & Live** mode

  1. Made API call to initiate Paypal transaction, received redirect URL
  2. Opened Url, Logged in, Confirmed payment, Redirected back to `return_url` with URL query from Paypal, including `paymentId` and `PayerID`

     - At this time, the `return_url` page only displays back the URL query, but doesn't process Paypal's *return callback*.
     - **Did not** receive *IPN* and *Webhook* in `callback_url`s
     - *IPN Hisotry* page and *Webhook Events* page **do not** show new events
  3. Modified code to process Paypal's *return callback* (namely, called `"/v1/payments/orders/{$this->getId()}/capture"`), and refreshed `return_url` page.

     - At this time, the `return_url` page shows the capture status, and transaction state, which is *successful*
     - **Did** receive *IPN* and *Webhook* in `callback_url`s
     - *IPN Hisotry* page and *Webhook Events* page **do** show new events

So... Are Paypal's IPN and Webhook both not meant for back-end notification, and front-end return processing is a must? But I've seen people claiming "in order to avoid the unreliable return_url not being triggered by the user's end, we should use IPN", etc. Am I missing something, or doing something wrong?

**UPDATE - include code**

1. My "Pay" button sends a POST to this URL: `https://*PUB_IP_ADDRESS*/v2/payment/paypal/sale` (`sale` or `order` for their corresponding actions) with this JSON content:

   ```
   {
       "order_id":"test-23-order",
       "amount":"0.01",
       "currency":"CAD",
       "description":"1753 total .01"
   }
   ```
2. In controller/repository, I tested with Omnipay and PaypalSDK.

   a. With Omnipay, this is done:

   ```
   // PaymentController.php
   ...
   $result = $this->gateway
       ->setOrderId($request->get('order_id'))
       ->setAmount($request->get('amount'))
       ->setCurrency($request->get('currency'))
       ->setDescription($request->get('description'))
       ->initPayment();
   ...
   ```

   Where `$this->gateway` is Omnipay's Paypal Gateway. Then:

   ```
   // OmnipayRepository.php
   ...
   public function initPayment(){
       if (is_null($this->payment_intent)){
           throw ExceptionMapping(40000,
               "You need to set payment intent first with setIntent()");
       }

       $payment_params = $this->getPaymentParameters();

       switch ($this->payment_intent){
           case self::INTENT_PREAUTH:
               $payment_action = $this->gateway->authorize($payment_params);
               break;
           case self::INTENT_SALE:
               $payment_action = $this->gateway->purchase($payment_params);
               break;
           default:
               throw ExceptionMapping(40000,
                   "{$this->payment_intent} is an invalid payment intent for this action");
       }

       $response = $payment_action->send();

       return $this->handleTransactionResponse($response);
   }
   ...
   ```

   where `handleTransactionResponse($response)` gets the returned JSON and save to model.

   b. With Paypal SDK:

   ```
   // PaymentController.php
   ...
    $paypal = new PaypalRepository();
       $payment = $paypal->initPayment(
           $request->get('amount'),
           $request->get('currency'),
           $request->get('description'),
           URL::to("/").config("paypal.options.returnUrl"),
           URL::to("/").config("paypal.options.cancelUrl"),
           'order',
           $request->get('order_id')
       );


       if ($payment['error']) {
           echo $payment['error']."ERR_PP";
       } else {
           $approvalUrl = $payment['payment']->getApprovalLink();
           echo $approvalUrl;
           exit;
       }
   ...
   ```

   and then

   ```
   // PaypalRepository.php::initPayment()
   ...

       $payment = null;

       $payer = new Payer();
       $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

       $item1 = new Item();
       $item1->setName($descr)
           ->setDescription($descr)
           ->setCurrency($currency)
           ->setQuantity(1)
           ->setSku($sku)// Similar to `item_number` in Classic API
           ->setPrice($total);

       $itemList = new ItemList();
       $itemList->setItems(array($item1));

       $details = new Details();
       $details->setShipping(0);
       $details->setTax(0);
       $details->setSubtotal($total);

       $amount = new Amount();
       $amount->setCurrency($currency);
       $amount->setTotal($total);
       $amount->setDetails($details);

       $transaction = new Transaction();
       $transaction->setAmount($amount);
       $transaction->setItemList($itemList);
       $transaction->setDescription($descr);
       $transaction->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

       $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
       $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($returnUrl);
       $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl);

       $payment = new Payment();
       $payment->setIntent($intent);
       $payment->setPayer($payer);
       $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
       $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

       $payment->create($this->apiContext);
   ```
3. Then Paypal will respond with this JSON:

   ```
   {
      "id":"PAY-4L424927Y2109544NLF2TY2A",
      "intent":"sale",
      "state":"created",
      "payer":{
         "payment_method":"paypal"
      },
      "transactions":[
         {
            "amount":{
               "total":"0.01",
               "currency":"CAD"
            },
            "description":"1716 total .01",
            "related_resources":[

            ]
         }
      ],
      "create_time":"2017-07-24T00:16:40Z",
      "links":[
         {
            "href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v1\/payments\/payment\/PAY-4L424927Y2109544NLF2TY2A",
            "rel":"self",
            "method":"GET"
         },
         {
            "href":"https:\/\/www.sandbox.paypal.com\/cgi-bin\/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-0GN55647HU250615H",
            "rel":"approval_url",
            "method":"REDIRECT"
         },
         {
            "href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v1\/payments\/payment\/PAY-4L424927Y2109544NLF2TY2A\/execute",
            "rel":"execute",
            "method":"POST"
         }
      ]
   }
   ```
4. I then goto the `approval_url`, and sign in with Paypal account to complete the approval for *sale* or *order* transaction.
5. Now we are back to the original bullet points (3) and (4) above, where Paypal would not trigger any IPN or Webhook event unless I process the data via `return_url` to complete the transaction, which in code, is this:

   a. Omnipay:

   ```
   // PaymentRepository.php, WIP code for callback_return
   ...
   public function callback_return(Request $request)
   {
       $paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
       $payerId = $_GET['PayerID'];

       // Once the transaction has been approved, we need to complete it.
       $transaction = $this->gateway->completePurchase(array(
           'payer_id'             => $payerId,
           'transactionReference' => $paymentId,
       ));
       $response = $transaction->send();
       if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
           // The customer has successfully paid.
           echo "PAID";
       } else {
           echo "ERROR";
           // There was an error returned by completePurchase().  You should
           // check the error code and message from PayPal, which may be something
           // like "card declined", etc.
       }
   }
   ...
   ```

   b. Paypal SDK:

   ```
   // paypal_return.php, code snippet on completing transaction
   ...
       $paypal = new paypal();
       try {
           $payment = $paypal->executePaypalIntent(get2('paymentId'), get2('PayerID'));
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           $payment = false;
       }
   ...
   ```

Comment: considering how many systems rely on this working, including several i maintain, im just going to have to say your wrong.

Comment: I use Paypal IPN as a backend-notification service and it really works great in all my projects. Please post your "pay" button and your IPN code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @patrick-simard. I've updated my question with relative codes. So your IPN triggers without any post-processing after user confirms the payment?

Comment: @rtfm, I would love to be proven wrong, that Paypal indeed handles IPN/Webhook correctly to my expectation, but I'm really lost in what could be wrong in  my code. It's done to Paypal SDK's standards and Omnipay's even simpler method.

Comment: Thx for the update. just created an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you dont reference the paypal ipn at all in your paypal button...

> Try adding notify_url

This is how I do it.

```
$_CONFIG['cart']['test'] = "1"; // 0 (paypal) | 1 (sandebox)
$_CONFIG['cart']['return'] = "http://thx.com";
$_CONFIG['cart']['ipn'] = "http://dev.com/ipn.php";

if (!$_CONFIG['cart']['test']){
    $_CONFIG['cart']['webscr'] = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?"; // paypal
    $_CONFIG['cart']['postback'] = "www.paypal.com";
    $_CONFIG['cart']['paypal'] = "commandes@dev.org";
}else{
    $_CONFIG['cart']['webscr'] = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?"; // sandebox
    $_CONFIG['cart']['postback'] = "www.sandbox.paypal.com";
    $_CONFIG['cart']['paypal'] = "info-facilitator@dev.com";
}

$grand_total = "9.99";

// Bouton Paypal
$paypalURL .= $_CONFIG['cart']['webscr'].'&';
$paypalURL .=  'item_name=ITEM NAME&';
$paypalURL .=  'cmd=_xclick&';
$paypalURL .=  'business='.urlencode($_CONFIG['cart']['paypal']).'&';
$paypalURL .=  'return='.urlencode($_CONFIG['cart']['return']).'&';
$paypalURL .=  'lc=CA&amount='.sprintf("%01.2f", $grand_total).'&';
$paypalURL .=  'currency_code=CAD&';
$paypalURL .=  'button_subtype=products&';
$paypalURL .=  'cn=Ajouter%20des%20instructions%20particuli%c3%a8res%20pour%20le%20vendeur&';
$paypalURL .=  'no_shipping=2&';
$paypalURL .=  'shipping=0&';
$paypalURL .=  'bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHosted&';
$paypalURL .=  'notify_url='.urlencode($_CONFIG['cart']['ipn']);
```

You can use the URL as a button or as a redirect. Just make sure you validate the amount paid on a successful transaction.

One thing you can do in your IPN code is to trigger a mail alert when it's executed and send your self the $_POST. At least you know when the IPN visited the page. Just make sure you add it on top in case there's a PHP error stopping the execution. If after receiving the mail the transaction is not processed then you know something is wrong and it's not Paypal's fault lol

IPN

```
<?php

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
    $mail .= "_POST[$key]: $value<br>";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: ".$_CONFIG['cart']['postback']."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://'.$_CONFIG['cart']['postback'], 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// Si le fsockopen a fonctionner on poursuit
if ($fp) {

    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {

        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (trim($res)=="VERIFIED") {


        }elseif ($res=="INVALID") {


        }else{


        }

    }

    // On ferme la connexion
    fclose ($fp);
}else{
    echo "404";
}

$subject = "IPN-DEBUG";
$messagez = "Paypal info:<br />$mail<br /><br />$prod_mail";
$de = "you@website.com";
send_mail($subject, $messagez, $de, 'you@website.com');  

function send_mail($subject, $message, $de, $to){

    require_once ('module/phpmailer/MailClass.php');//send_mail

    $send_mail = new FreakMailer();
    $send_mail->Subject = $subject;
    $send_mail->Body = $message;
    $send_mail->isHTML(true);
    $send_mail->From = $de;
    $send_mail->AddAddress($to);

    if(!$send_mail->Send()){return 'false';}else{return 'true';}
    $send_mail->ClearAddresses();
    $send_mail->ClearAttachments();

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and heads up! I will be sure to test the code again with `notify_url` and report back. Strangely, though, as I thought I've tested that already, but perhaps did not configure it correctly. I also did not pay much attention to this part during testing, because I thought both IPN and Webhook would rely on and default to their initial setup URL in Paypal's developer portal and Business profile setting. In fact, I've read some developers encountered their `notify_url` setting does not take effect over the initial settings... Besides, what about _webhook_ not triggering?

Comment: Turns out, both Omnipay and PayPal's SDK do not have `setNotifyUrl()` method. So I tried your code instead (with modifications to options such as `$_CONFIG['cart']['ipn']`, `$_CONFIG['cart']['paypal']`, etc)... However, when I access the URL, Paypal just shows an error page saying _"Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."_ I guess we are using different Paypal's payment methods? Now I'm at a dead end again...

Comment: I think you need to go back to basics. Above is a working IPN shell and a working paypal link. Your doing something wrong. Change the paypal email, set up a temp paypal ipn (direct url to php file) modify only the mailer() function to receive a mail and debug your way from there.